# Which method is called when taking a picture during auto mission?

Tags: swift, dji-sdk

I would like to know when the trigger is fired on an auto-mission. It is simple with products with internal storage, for example the following method updates an image count label for every new picture taken

```
func camera(_ camera: DJICamera, didGenerateNewMediaFile newMedia: DJIMediaFile) {
 self.picsTaken += 1
 self.picsTakenLabel.text = "Pics taken: \(picsTaken)"
}
```

Of course, this does not work for devices like the M600 with a RoninMX and a Remote S/S trigger, as there is no information of the internal storage.

I also tried the following:

```
func camera(_ camera: DJICamera, didUpdate systemState: DJICameraSystemState) {
    if systemState.isShootingSinglePhoto {
...
    }
}
```

But that method doesn't even get called on our M600.

Does anyone know if there a method or parameter that gets called or changed when an auto-mission fires the trigger?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will help you.

```
DJIWaypoint wp = new DJIWaypoint(latitude, longitude, altitude);

DJIWaypoint.DJIWaypointAction takePictureAction = new DJIWaypoint.DJIWaypointAction(DJIWaypoint.DJIWaypointActionType.StartTakePhoto, 0);

wp.addAction(takePictureAction);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you tried observing the [camera status](https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/ios-api/Components/Camera/DJICamera_DJICameraSystemState.html)?

You must register the camera delegate and then in the `didUpdate` method check for 
the value of `isShootingSinglePhoto` property.

Something like this

```
class ViewController: DJICameraDelegate....

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    ...
    self.camera!.delegate = self
    ...
}

func camera(_ camera: DJICamera, didUpdate systemState: DJICameraSystemState) {
    if systemState.isShootingSinglePhoto {
        doSomething()
    }
}
```